# Подключение к SQL Express LocalDB

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, sql-server-localdb

При переносе БД SQL Express LocalDB на другой ПК,  после установки выдает ошибку сервер не найден или недоступен.

Подключался через:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=| DataDirectory |\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

Работает с ошибкой.

Изменил на:

```
string executable=System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
string connectionString = @"Data Source(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename =| DataDirectory |\Database.mdf; Integrated Security = True; User Instance = True";
```

Ошибка ключа.

Comment: LocalDB - это СУБД для разработчиков, она ставится вместе с Visual Studio. На другом компьютере (если он не используется для разработки) её вполне может не быть. Там должна быть установлена любая другая версия SqlServer. Естественно, в строке подключения нужно указать именно тот сервер. То есть, строку подключения **нельзя** зашивать в код. Она должна быть вынесена в конфиг и т. п. И при инсталляции на другом компьютере эта строка заменяется на правильную.

Comment: Кроме того, я вижу следующие ошибки: пропущен знак равно после Data Source, и, возможно, здесь не должно быть пробелов: `| DataDirectory |`. Но в этом не уверен.

Comment: SQL Server Express устанавливается  на другой ПК из установочника.
Слегка не понимаю, как вставить подключение в config.

Comment: [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)

Comment: Добавил
 <add name="Database" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\Databse.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
В основной форме жалуется на
await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
  (System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.")